# Vertically stack multiple images using ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, image-processing

I would like to combine multiple images into one image using ImageMagick. To explain a little better, I want the result to look similar to this:

[image]

That is, I have a number of screenshots, and I want to turn them into one image with the original images on top of each other.

By Googling, I have come across the 'composite' command, but I don't know if, and in that case how to use it to get the result I want.

Comment: Did you check out [imagemagick multi image layer examples](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/layers/)?

Answer (score 385, accepted):

For any number of input files
named `in-<something>.jpg`:

```
convert -append in-*.jpg out.jpg
```

In order to have specific files appended, or skip numbers instead of getting the full "glob", you can mention the input files explicitly and put the `append` command afterwards

```
convert in-1.jpg in-5.jpg in-N.jpg +append out-in1-plus-in5-and-inN.jpg
```

You can use `-append` (instead of `+append`) for vertical paste-up.

Or:

```
montage -mode concatenate -tile 1x in-*.jpg out.jpg
```

will also create a file `out.jpg` that contains a vertical concatenation of the source images.

### `convert`

For simple concatenation in a single row or column, the `append` option of the `convert` tool is sufficient. Note that `-append` concatenates all images vertically, creating one column with *n* rows,
and `+append` concatenates horizontally, creating one row with *n* columns.

(See [ImageMagick: Command-line Options](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#append).)

### `montage`

To get finer control over the layout, we would need the `montage` tool. `montage -mode concatenate` will glue the input images together like the `append` option and `-tile 1x` controls the layout to be applied.

`tile` follows the format *columns*×*rows*, but either side may be missing and `montage` will figure out how to meet the constraints.

We're using `1x` (exactly one column with any number of rows) here to get the same effect as `-append`. Without `-tile 1x`, it would join the images like `+append`, defaulting to `-tile x1` (any number of columns on one row).

(See [ImageMagick Examples: Montage, Arrays of Images](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/).)

Comment: Thanks. append works fine, but I consider montage broken: if ghostscript fonts are not installed, it will bail out, EVEN if you are not annotating the images. Fonts should be loaded on demand, not in advance.

Comment: How would I skip every other image? I'd like to parse a subset - in-1, in-3, in-5, etc..

Comment: @MikeRobinson ``convert -append `counter=0; for x in in-*; do if [[ $(($counter % 2)) == 0 ]]; then echo $x; fi; counter=$((counter + 1)); done` out.jpg`` should do the job.

Comment: @peth: Your answer starts with an example `convert` command that has `-append` ***before*** input file names.  An anonymous user added an example with `+append` ***after*** the input file names.  Are these both valid?  Is the order significant?

Comment: Note that the `convert -tile 2x2` etc. command will read the files **alphabetically**. This means that chunks named `0-10` will be read like `0,10,1,2,..,9`. Took me almost 2 hours to realize something this basic.

Comment: @Blauhirn: Is that convert sorting the filenames, or is that just your glob returning files in that order? e.g. `ls *` will return those values in that order.

Comment: @naught101 Oh, you are right! I must have been using a glob there.

Comment: I needed to add "magick" to the beginning of the command to make it work for me on Windows 11 from PowerShell.  `magick convert -append *.jpg out.jpg`

Comment: `convert` doesn't work for me. It generates multiple `out` files that are just plain copies of the originals

Answer (score 13):

**Use `-resize`  if the images don't have the same width/height**

You can fix the height for all of them with the `-resize` option, e.g. to fix a 500 pixel height on two images joined horizontally:

```
convert +append image_1.png image_2.png -resize x500 new_image_conbined.png
```

Or for vertical joins, you would want to set a fixed width instead:

```
convert -append image_1.png image_2.png -resize 500x new_image_conbined.png
```

Example:

image_1.png 1067x600

[image]

image_2.png 1920x1080

[image]

new_image_conbined.png 889x500

[image]

**How to do it interactively with GIMP**

If you need to crop/resize images interactively first, which is often the case, then GIMP is the perfect tool for it, here's a detailed step-by-step: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/83446/gimp-how-to-combine-two-images-side-by-side/145543#145543

[image]

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737061/merge-images-side-by-sidehorizontally
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/226054/how-do-i-join-two-images-together

**SVGs**

ImageMagick 6.9.11-60 doesn't handle them, so see:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612434/how-to-concatenate-svg-files-lengthwise-from-linux-command-line
- https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/137096/is-there-a-way-to-stack-two-svgs-on-top-of-each-other
- https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/90844/joining-together-multiple-svg-images