# convert multiple jpg into one with linux

Tags: linux, image-conversion

I have multiple jpg that come from a scanner. I want to combine all into one ? how ?
I have seen something like

```
$ convert -adjoin *.jpg one.jpg
```

but it create multiple one.jpg images.

Comment: wouldn't you be better off scanning it into a multi-page pdf ?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/290656/combine-multiple-images-using-imagemagick

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using ImageMagick 6.7.6:

```
convert.exe  bishop.png \
    -append king.png \
    -append queen.png \
    -background none  \
    -append pieces.png
```

## Pieces.png:

[image: stacked images]

Comment: http://imagemagick.org/Usage/layers/#append