# Can't use the * with ImageMagick : I get "Invalid argument"

Tags: command-line, imagemagick

Using the example provided there : [Combine multiple images using ImageMagick](https://superuser.com/questions/290656/combine-multiple-images-using-imagemagick?newreg=13db788d40f642c5a8ed1231c0da573b)

I type this in command line in windows 7 :

```
convert -append a_*.jpg out.jpg
```

This is the error message I get :

> convert.exe: unable to open image `a_*.jpg': Invalid argument @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2658.
>   convert.exe: no images defined`out.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3187.

I have the jpg files in the directory, and it works if I use this code instead :

```
 convert -append a_1.jpg a_2.jpg a_3.jpg out.jpg
```

I assume that I have a syntax problem because of the * but I can't understand how to make it work.
In this example I have 3 files, but I need the * because I want to use it for a much bigger list of jpgs...

Do you know where is my problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You have the syntax mostly right.

Try the syntax below to put images side by side:

```
convert a_1.jpg a_2.jpg a_3.jpg +append out.jpg
```

[image: side by side]

If you wanted the images top to bottom, you would type:

```
convert a_1.jpg -append a_2.jpg -append a_3.jpg -append out.jpg
```

[image: top to bottom]

ImageMagic allows you to achieve the same result in many different ways. This is the beauty and frustration with the software. :)